# Any Angular directive works like Rails link_to(:method => "POST"?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive, form-submit, link-to

As title, I would like to use AngularJS to generate a link that works like a submit button of a form.

In Rails, I can achieve this by the `link_to` method: `link_to "Cancel", bookings_path(@booking), :method => "DELETE"`. And then Rails will generate a hidden form for me to simulate form submitting when the link is clicked.

Is there any AngularJS directive can do this for me?

[EDIT]

What I want is a pure Angular way for this:

```
/ in some haml file
= link_to "Cancel", nil, :method => 'DELETE', :"ng-href" => "/bookings/{{id}}/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but may be this will help you,

```
%a{href: 'bookings/{{@booking}}'} 'Delete'
```